# Trigger on cascading update

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement where i am creating child records when lead is getting created.

On Lead conversion those records are getting attached to opportunity as child records

I have trigger to be fired on those child records after those are attached to the opportunity on lead conversion

I know triggers wont fire on cascade update.But i require an alternate solution for updating the count of child records on opportunity

Comment: i can provide additional steps to create rollup summary if you want.

Comment: the created on lead object when is it converted i.e and update action is performed on lead and it give the converted opportunity
which has to be updated.

Comment: What do you mean you know the triggers wont fire on cascade update? It sounds like you're saying records are being created on a child object and the trigger isn't firing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom field to store the count of related records associated to lead Object.

You can have a custom field on Opportunity and then map that count on lead against opportunity custom field using lead TO Account/Contact/ Opportunity Mapping.

during lead conversion, the count of related records would be mapped to opportunity custom field.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a rollup summary field in the parent object which is in your case is Opportunity. But the child objects to opportunity should be master-detail.

Comment: we have look up relation and that cannot be changed to masterdetail

Comment: we are updating the values in parent object  using trigger

Comment: rollup summary field is the easiest way and since its has been already setup as look up relationship the trigger is the second option.